# Functional tests in Symfony 3.2.4 using phpStorm

Tags: symfony, unit-testing, functional-testing

I have difficulties setting up a functional test in Symfony 3.2.4.

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ClinicalTrialsControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testHTTPConnection()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
```

The client is not created and I constantly get an error message:

```
Unable to guess the Kernel directory.
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/coremed/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:57
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/coremed/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:118
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/coremed/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:164
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/coremed/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:145
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/coremed/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:33
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/coremed/Tests/Controller/ClinicalTrialsControllerTest.php:17
```

In phpunit.dist.xml the kernel directory is set to

```
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value='app/' />
    </php>
```

Any hints as to how to set the kernel directory?

Comment: Weird to have this value for KERNEL_DIR the default one is `app/` like the answer below.

Comment: how did you run the phpunit?

Answer (score 3):

I have this in my phpunit.dist.xml:

```
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
</php>
```

Why don't you change it and see if that works?

Comment: I have tried  'app/', as well as full path or relative path, but it did'nt change anything

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
phpunit.xml.dist
```

Not `phpunit.dist.xml`.