# Symfony2 Unit test

Tags: symfony, testunit

When I run the method test I get the following problem. How can I fix it?

```
Unable to guess the Kernel directory.
 C:\Users\HAMDI\Documents\resment-hr\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php:58
 C:\Users\HAMDI\Documents\resment-hr\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php:119
 C:\Users\HAMDI\Documents\resment-hr\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php:165
 C:\Users\HAMDI\Documents\resment-hr\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php:146
 C:\Users\HAMDI\Documents\resment-hr\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase.php:33
 C:\Users\HAMDI\Documents\resment-hr\src\Intexsoft\ResmentBundle\Tests\Controller\DisplayControllerTest.php:19
```

Comment: Check out a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527979/functional-tests-in-symfony-3-2-4-using-phpstorm